# Generate a heatmap in a set X, Y, Z with Z being the intensity of the color

Tags: matlab, colors, heatmap, xyz

I have a numerical set X, Y, Z and I would like to reproduce a heatmap with these values. The size of the bin is 20 x 20 and the range of the X and Y axes are from -150 to 150 with Z being the color. Within that bin it should contain the average of the Z values in that range.

In Origin contains this tool to make a heatmap with the average of the values, but I would like to do it in MATLAB. The graph I made in Origin and that I would like to do in MATLAB can be seen in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNBlc.png).

[image: Figure 1]

I've tried something like

```
load xyz.dat 
x = xyz(:,1); 
y = xyz(:,2);
z = xyz(:,3); 
tbl = table(x,y,z); 
h = heatmap(tbl,'x','y','ColorVariable','z','ColorMethod','mean');
```

But it printed this warning

> Warning: Error updating HeatmapChart. Values in the source table variable 'x' are not grouped into discrete categories. Use the discretize function to group your values.

Comment: try `heatmap(x,y,z,"ColorMethod","mean")` should catch most of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @greengrass62 , I can't make this code. I tried something like:

`load xyz.dat

x = xyz(:,1);

y = xyz(:,2);

z = xyz(:,3);

tbl = table(x,y,z);

h = heatmap(tbl,'x','y','ColorVariable','z','ColorMethod','mean'); `

and this message appears:

_Warning: Error updating HeatmapChart._

 _Values in the source table variable 'x' are not grouped into discrete categories. Use the discretize function to group your values._

Comment: Are the x,y,z values always in a grid?

Comment: @Cecilia Yes they are.  As there are many values, here is a small part here: `x = [49.8, 14.5, -60.7, -21.6, -10.6]`, `y = [45.3, 7.9, 23.9, -58.5, -55.4]`, `z = [0.2 , -0.06, -0.35, -0.15, -0.08]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`heatmap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html) expects discrete x and y values. You goal is to bin your x and y's into 20 discrete bins and average the z values for each bin, but x and y themselves are continuous.

To achieve your goal take the advice of the warning message and use [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.discretize.html) to bin your x and y values.

```
% I used the following stand ins for your data:
% x = rand(540, 1);
% y = rand(540, 1);
% z = rand(540, 1);

n_bins = 20; % Number of grid cells
% If you want the width of the grid cell to be 20, use 
% n_bins = (max(x) - min(x)) / 20; 

x_discrete = discretize(x, n_bins);
y_discrete = discretize(y, n_bins);
tbl = table(x_discrete,y_discrete,z, 'VariableNames', {'x', 'y', 'z'});
h = heatmap(tbl,'x','y','ColorVariable','z','ColorMethod','mean');
```

[image: Heatmap of discretized variables]

### Note: Why was this not a problem with the sample data?

Using your sample data,

```
x = [49.8, 14.5, -60.7, -21.6, -10.6];
y = [45.3, 7.9, 23.9, -58.5, -55.4];
z = [0.2 , -0.06, -0.35, -0.15, -0.08];
tbl = table(x',y',z', 'VariableNames', {'x', 'y', 'z'});
h = heatmap(tbl,'x','y','ColorVariable','z','ColorMethod','mean');
```

Does not throw an error because it treats each x and y value as a separate category. `heatmap` uses a call to [`categorical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) to transform the continuous values into categorical values.

Aside from not really providing the output you want (each point would be its own box instead of averaging grid cells), `categorical` seems to have a limit in how many categorical values it will create. I wasn't able to find any documentation about exactly what that limit is, but by experimentation, it tops out in the mid 200's. Since your vectors are 540 elements long, you get the warning about using `discretize` instead.

Comment: The same error appeared. It must be because my sample is imported from xyz.dat, but how do I fix it? thank you so much for trying to help me

Comment: What is size(x) with your real data?

Comment: 540 values. I would send you the file, but I don't think it's possible to send it.

Comment: What about the dimensions? Is it a row vector or a column vector?

Comment: the `xyz.dat` is a matrix 3x540, so `x = xyz(:,1)` is a column vector 1x540.

Comment: @SarahGomes I've updated my answer. The solution was staring us in the face the whole time in the warning message. :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's what I wanted, but the x and y axes must be between -150 and 150.